# How check touch event

Tags: android

I searching about method which I check which way I touch screen and after that send information to touch event. I want to check if I touch screen one finger or two fingers or I move finger on screen. This is any method to check what I am doing my fingers on the screen befor application do some actions?

Comment: Have a glance of this link:http://www.androidadb.com/class/android/view/View/OnTouchListener.java.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this one.

A drag gesture starts when the first finger is pressed to the screen (**ACTION_DOWN**) and ends when it is removed (**ACTION_UP** or **ACTION_POINTER_UP**).

```
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         savedMatrix.set(matrix);
         start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
         Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
         mode = DRAG;
         break;
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

     case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
         mode = NONE;
         Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
         break;
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         if (mode == DRAG) {
             matrix.set(savedMatrix);
             matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
         }
         break;
}
```

for complete information check [here](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-5-implementing-the-drag-gesture/1789)

```
                             (or)
```

for document check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)