# Handling drag and touch inside onTouch

Tags: android

How to distinguish between Touch and drag in android... I want to create a listview in which people can drag and drop list items,that too with out using a handle...
What I have tried and failed is..

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
mIsClickX   =   x;
mIsClickY   =   y;

and 

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
if(x == mIsClickX &&y == mIsClickY){
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Which doesn't work...
Thanks in advance for all your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, you can also check:
1- http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747
2- [Android List View Drag and Drop sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909311/android-list-view-drag-and-drop-sort)

Comment: Well, I am using the library in a link you just specified(https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview). But that includes a handler(An Image) which when clicked and dragged causes the list view elements to move around. I don't want that Image.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this one.

A drag gesture starts when the first finger is pressed to the screen (ACTION_DOWN) and ends when it is removed (ACTION_UP or ACTION_POINTER_UP).

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11391358/1265724)

Comment: Yes...I agree But how to distinguish between a drag and touch event??
I mean a touch also has ACTION_DOWN...I tried taking the pressed position and cross checking that on the ACTION_UP which doesn't work unfortunately...